# SingleEmailMessage CC is not working

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

I'm trying to send emails with TO, CC and BCC addresse

```
 mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplateId);
  mail.setTargetObjectId(emailTargetId);
  mail.setSenderDisplayName(Label.Sender_Name);
  mail.setReplyTo(Label.Sender_Email);
  mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{'a@a.com'});
  mail.setCcAddresses(new String[]{'b@a.com'});
  mail.setBccAddresses(new String[]{'c@a.com'});
 Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

The email is sent ok, but all address are **always in TO**.

Any clue ?

Comment: I still having this problem anyone can help me ?

Comment: I opened a case for this  but without answer so far.